# Selecting <span />s inside a <li /> inside a <ul /> with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the next code:

```
<ul>
    <li id="cat-12">
        <span id="subcat-13">lorem</span>
        <span id="subcat-43">ipsum</span>
    </li>
    <li id="cat-41">
        <span id="subcat-22">lorem</span>
        <span id="subcat-23">ipsum</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How I can select all `<span />` IDs? So I get an array with: subcat-13, subcat-43, subcat-22, subcat-23?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to loop with `each`, instead use `map`<sup>([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/))</sup> like this:

```
var arr = $('ul li span').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/qdAnx/

Comment: You can add a `toArray()` (or `get()`) at the end to turn the jQuery object into a plain array.

Comment: you could just use this.id, then you dont need to create a jquery object.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = new Array();

$('ul > li > span').each(function() {
    array.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Rather than push them all into an array like that you could just use `$('ul > li > span').toArray();`

Comment: @Samich: Thank you! That worked! One more thing, how I can know if array is not empty? So I've at least 1 value? Thank you!

Comment: @udexter - use `.length` to determine the length of the array.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a pure Array with just the ID you can select all the span:

```
var span = $("ul li span");
```

and then loop them with .each()

```
var span = $("ul li span"),
    arr = [];

span.each(function() {
    if(this.id) {
        arr.push(this.id);
    }
});
```